# Delete Managed Object using Core data/Restkit

Tags: iphone, core-data, restkit

I have to delete local store data (orphaned objects) which is no longer returned by server. I am using the following code when initilializing object manager.

```
[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
            RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/relative_path"];

            NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
            BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
            if (match) {
                NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Articles"];
                return fetchRequest;
            }

            return nil;
        }];
```

In the above code, 'match' condition returns TRUE. But Fetch Request doesn't delete the orphaned objects which was not returned by the server.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the "Fetch Request Blocks and Deleting Orphaned Objects" approach which is documented [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html).

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I have added the function in My AppDelegate. But when the url matches, it is returning all objects including deleted object from the server. is there any thing i need to do?. i have updated my qn.pls look on that.

Comment: It should return all items. RestKit will compare the fetch result with the server result and delete items that aren't returned from the server.

Comment: But when i check my DB. Old data is still present in table.

Comment: Is the table triggered to update when the MOC is saved? And you checked (debugged) that the fetch request is created and returned?

Comment: No I am not triggering table to update. Also when i debugged the fetch request, it is returning
<NSFetchRequest: 0xd534d80> (entity: Articles; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

Comment: So you need to trigger the table view to update - it won't happen automatically.

Comment: I mean, do i need to update DB Table that showing old record.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34903/discussion-between-iphone-guy-and-wain)